# Wrap in special div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working for some template, but have confused about wrapping div tags on `H2`, this is my script :

HTML:

```
<style>
.widget-title{
border:3px solid black;
}
</style>
<div id="widget">
<h2>Title 1.1</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Item 1.1.1</li>
   <li>Item 1.1.2</li>
   <li>Item 1.1.3</li>
</ul>
<br />
<h2>Title 1.2</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Item 1.2.1</li>
   <li>Item 1.2.2</li>
   <li>Item 1.2.3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<br />
<div class="footer">
<h2>Title 2</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('widget')
$('h2').each(function(){
   var self = $(this);
   self.wrapAll('<div class="widget-title" />');
});
</script>
```

I want to add tag  for every H2 tags, but only inside `div id="widget"` tags, I mean like:

```
<div id="widget"><div class="widget-title"><h2>title</h2></div</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restrict your selector to `h2`s inside `#widget` and use [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$('#widget h2').wrap('<div class="widget-title" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to target only those `h2` which are descendants of `div` with the `id` "widget":

```
$('div#widget h2').each(function(){
   var self = $(this);
   self.wrapAll('<div class="widget-title" />');
});
```

You also could do well with just `wrap` although, because you are only targeting one `h2` in the `each`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
$(function(){
    $('h2').wrap('<div class="widget-title" />');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0ozb3bc/

Not clear on if you want it to affect h2s in the footer or not. If you don't you'll have to change h2 to #widget h2.